# Verifying Lightweight Core Data Migration

Tags: core-data, migration

I'm running a Core Data migration that adds a single inverse relationship to get rid of a warning I had.

After running the migration, how can I verify that the models I'm now using are referring to a specific xcdatamodel version (the latest one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightweight migrations always target the latest model. If the migration succeeds, then the model you're using is the one marked as "current" in Xcode. In nearly every case, this is all you need.

If you want further confirmation:

In Xcode, you can add an identifier string to the data model, which can be different for each version of the model. You do this by selecting a version the data model in the file browser and opening the file inspector on the right side of the Xcode window. You'll see a section labeled "Identifier":

[image: model identifier]

Enter any string that makes sense to you. At run time you can look up the value of this string using something like

```
let modelIdentifiers = context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel.versionIdentifiers
```

This returns a set, because a model can be created by merging multiple model files. It will contain the string you entered above.

But this is almost never necessary. You can rely on the fact that the migration is using whichever model is marked as current in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington !  Yeah I wanted a way to verify at runtime as well.